# how set default active tab in laravel javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

How i can i get my first tab active and selected, because because when i load my page none of my tabs selected and active.

this is the Tabs  when the page loaded

[image]

and this is after clicking the tab

[image]

**html**

```
                     <div class="tabbable-line ">

                        <!-- Nav Nav-tabs Start -->
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs_content">
                            @foreach ($routes as $route)
                                <li  >
                                    <a href="#{{ $route->id }}" id="ad" data-toggle="tab">
                                        {!! $route->name !!}
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>

                        <div class="tab-content blog_tabs">
                            <!-- tab-content is coming from javascript -->
                        </div>
                   </div>
```

**nav-content** are in javascript because there's data coming from controller when ever tab is selected, so here is...

Nav content **Javascript**

```
$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("href").replace("#", "");
        console.log(id);

        if(id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "{{ route('user.schedule.getId') }}",
                type: "GET",
                data:{'id':id},
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(data) {
                    $(".tab-content").empty();
                    $(".tab-content").html('<div class="tab-pane" name="schedule" id="'+ id +'">')
                    $.each( data, function( index, object ) {
                        $(".tab-content").append('<ul class="list-group"><li class="list-group-item">'+ object['schedule_number'] +'</li></ul></div>');

                    });

                }
            });
        }    
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your foreach loop, add a class ***active*** for the first item in your array:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs_content">
   @foreach ($routes as $index => $route)
      <li {{ $index== 0 ? 'class="active"' : '' }}>
         <a href="#{{ $route->id }}" id="ad{{ $route->id }}" data-toggle="tab">
            {!! $route->name !!}
         </a>
      </li>
   @endforeach
</ul>
```

Add please notice that id have to be unique in your document.

Comment: thansk for your answer, but it's the same error no default tab

Comment: I forgot the dollar sign for the index variable--> `@foreach ($routes as $index => $route)` or you can try this syntax : `<li @if($index== 0) class="active" @endif> `

Comment: the `nav-tab` is active but there's not content... i mean the first tab is active but it's content is not active, and thanks for that

Comment: try to add this line `$(document).$("ul.nav-tabs > li:first > a").trigger( "click" );` under the `$("ul.nav-tabs > li > a").click(function() { ... })` snippet ..like this you are triggering a click event for the first element in your list to get its content generated.

Comment: javascript error is coming out  `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).$ is not a function`...  is this a normal ?
 `

Comment: Sorry .. remove document --> `$("ul.nav-tabs > li:first > a").trigger( "click" );`

Comment: finally... that's great, thank you. now it's as i wanted

Comment: please update your answer, so people  that come after this error get it!